# strings and pointers

Tags: c

I am new to C and reviewing some source code. But I am not sure what is happening with this code snippet.

I really don't think it is doing anything, as in the debugging the output seems to be the same for tempstr.

This is what I think, correct if I am wrong.
*(tempstr + strlen(line)) is adding the length of line to tempstr and dereferencing and assigning the 0x0 converted to a char?

```
char line[128], tempstr[128]

strcpy(line, "AUTO_ANSWER_CALL = 1");
strcpy(tempstr,line);
*(tempstr + strlen(line)) = (char) 0x0; // Confusing part
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pointer value:

```
tempstr
```

This is another pointer value (which points to `5` elements beyond the `tempstr` pointer value):

```
tempstr + 5
```

This is an integer:

```
strlen(line)
```

Therefore, this is a pointer value (which points to `strlen(line)` elements beyond the `tempstr` pointer value):

```
tempstr + strlen(line)
```

And this is dereferencing that pointer:

```
*(tempstr + strlen(line))
```

---

> This is what I think, correct if I am wrong. *(tempstr + strlen(line)) is adding the length of line to tempstr and dereferencing and assigning the 0x0 converted to a char?

It's ensuring that the character at index 20 of tempstr, immediately beyond the "AUTO_ANSWER_CALL = 1" characters, is null: i.e. it's ensuring that the string is null-terminated.

That string already is null-terminated, by the way (so that last statement is redundent): because strcpy copies the string including the implicit null-termination character.

---

> Isn't easier just to do the following tempstr[sizeof(tempstr)-1] = '\0'; this is much easier to understand.

These aren't the same thing: `strlen(line)` equals 20, but `sizeof(tempstr)` equals 128.

---

> would this work: tempstr[strlen(tempstr)] = '\0'

That's exactly the same things as:

```
*(tempstr + strlen(tempstr)) = '\0'
```

Just a different way of writing it.

> However, if tempstr is NOT a null terminated string, the length would be 128 as well.

If tempstr is NOT a null terminated string then `strlen(tempstr)` is undefined ('undefined' means that it's meaningless and dangerous, a bug, and shouldn't be used): the `strlen` function isn't valid except when it's used on a string that's already null-terminated.

Comment: would this work: tempstr[strlen(tempstr)] = '\0'; However, if tempstr is NOT a null terminated string, the length would be 128 as well. Because I am getting the length of a undetermined length? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

First, note that the code is crap.

```
*(tempstr + strlen(line)) = (char) 0x0;
```

It looks like the original author wasn't too sure if `strcpy` copied the terminating nul character so he made doubly sure instead of checking the manual (btw, ***`strcpy` does copy the terminating null***).

That is basically the same as:

```
tempstr[ strlen(line) ] = (char) 0;
```

The cast to `char` is there, I guess, because of the possibility of a C++ compiler being used to compile this code.

I am not sure why

```
char line[128] = "AUTO_ANSWER_CALL = 1";
```

was not acceptable.

Comment: Assumably, whoever originally wrote the code heard that `char *line = "whatever";` leaves an unmodifiable string, and didn't know that `char line[128] = "whatever"` works differently. Or didn't know about the latter at all.

Answer (score 2):

It does nothing. It tries to null-terminate a string which is already terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it is placing a null terminator (Char 0) at the end of the data it has copied into **tempstr** using *strcpy()*.

```
strcpy(tempstr, line)
```

Copies the contents of **line** into **tempstr**, but the author is perhaps unsure whether **tempstr** will be null terminated after this operation.  My C is rusty, and to be fair, I'm not sure either.  :)

However, for the code to work as intended I think **line**, and therefore **tempstr**, must be already null terminated (*strlen(**line**)* will count to the first null terminator), so for the code to work as expected it must also be utterly redundant, as *strcpy()* will have copied the null terminator when it copied **line** in the first place!

i.e. **// Confusing part** is actually a null operation and can be removed.  :)

Answer (score 2):

As said by others here code is basically adding a '\0' at the end of the string even though it is already present. Is this all of the code or there are lines in between? It could make some sense if say a memcpy() is used in between those lines.
On the lighter note the code was probably written by a myopic geek who suffered from a inferiority complex.

Comment: The line is initialized by using fgets from a file pointer. I just added it here to make the code more simple. However, I am sure there are other ways to terminate a string?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is zero-terminating the string.

Comment: Isn't easier just to do the following tempstr[sizeof(tempstr)] = '\0'; this is much easier to understand.

Comment: sorry, that should be: tempstr[sizeof(tempstr) -0] = '\0';

Comment: sorry, maybe rushing too much here should have been minus 1 instead of zero.

Comment: Actually it needs to be -1 as originally stated, otherwise you would replace the last character of the original string with a zero byte.  The total length of the string is sizeof(tempstr) if you include the null terminator, but the array is zero-based so you end up with the first solution being correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
*(tempstr + strlen(line)) = (char) 0x0; // Confusing part
// or
tempstr[strlen(line)]) = '\0'; // null terminate
```

It's superfluous because strcpy() will do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to understand that string constants like `"AUTO_ANSWER_CALL = 1"` must be assumed to be immutable. So what goes on here is two string buffers are declared:

```
char line[128], tempstr[128]; // <== better have the semicolon
```

at this point their contents are totally unknown.

Next a prepared text is copied into one of them.

```
strcpy(line, "AUTO_ANSWER_CALL = 1");
```

and then into the other

```
strcpy(tempstr,line);
```

Finally a little pointer arithmetic is used to stick a null character `'\0' == 0x0` onto the end to ensure that the string is properly terminated:

```
*(tempstr + strlen(line)) = (char) 0x0; // Confusing part
```

which is equivalent to

```
tempstr[strlen(line)] = (char) 0x0;
```